do multi sets violate our axioms
I was talking with someone about solution sets for polynomials:

I said $x\left(x - 1\right)=0$ and $x^{2}\left(x - 1\right) = 0$ has the same solution set $\left\{0,1\right\}$, but he said that you have to use multi sets so that the second one is $\left\{0,0,1\right\}$ to account for multiplicity and that this is different from $\left\{0,1\right\}$.
So I checked the ZFC axioms and the first one is "if $X$ and $Y$ have the same elements then $X=Y$".
Compare $\left\{0,0,1\right\}$ with
$\left\{0,1\right\}$. The first one has a $0$. So does the second. The first one has a $0$. So does the second. The first one has $\mbox{a}\ 1$. So does the second. And it works the same backwards. $$
\mbox{Therefore,}\quad
\left\{0,0,1\right\} = \left\{0,1\right\}
$$
Here's my thought:
If multi sets are a thing then they violate the axioms.
But if they violate the axioms then we don't know what $x\left(x - 1\right) = 0$ and
$x^{2}\left(x - 1\right) = 0$ mean in the model of axioms that allows multi sets, because it's a different set of rules so things will be different.
So to even say that the multi set is different from the regular set means we aren't talking about the same thing because I don't know what a polynomial is under his new system of axioms, so if he means the same thing he should be using ZFC which means multi sets don't exist. Is that
right ?.


Multisets are different structures than sets. They don’t violate ZFC, if you’ve defined them in some consistent way based on ZFC. But they are not sets. An example of how you could define them is saying the multiset ${0,0,1}$ is really shorthand for the set ${(0,1),(0,2),(1,1)}$

Just read https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Multiset (section on definition) s

Multisets are a thing and does not violate the ZFC axioms. IF you treat them like sets you'll get contradictions. It seems to me that your problem lies in the notation. If we choose another notation like $\langle\!|\,a,b,c\,|\!\rangle$ then $\langle\!|\,0,0,1\,|\!\rangle \ne \langle\!|\,0,1\,|\!\rangle$ does not conflict with $\{0,0,1\}=\{0,1\}$.
For convenience , when the context is clear, the usual notation for sets is used also for multisets and the reader is expected to use common sense to understand the abuse of notation.
